# Create a view with add new column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to create a view from two tables `dbo.Master` and `dbo.Economics` and create a new column just for view to get the source value on my created view so I know where that row came from.

Please see example below

**MasterTable**

| ID | EmployeeID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | John |
| 2 | 456 | Nico |
| 3 | 768 | Jam |
| 4 | 342 | Jom |
| 5 | 142 | Carlo |

**ResourceTable**

| ID | EmployeeID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | John |
| 2 | 456 | Nico |
| 3 | 444 | Don |
| 4 | 143 | Addie |

**Output**

| ID | EmployeeID | Name | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | John | MasterTable |
| 2 | 456 | Nico | MasterTable |
| 3 | 768 | Jam | MasterTable |
| 4 | 342 | Jom | MasterTable |
| 5 | 142 | Carlo | MasterTable |
| 6 | 444 | Don | ResourceTable |
| 7 | 143 | Addie | ResourceTable |

**The output should not have duplicate**

I am not sure how to do this in SQL but I am looking at doing union for the two table although the columns are different name.

Edit: I was able to get it running from a select

```
SELECT EmplyoeeID, 'Master' as Source FROM MasterTable 
UNION ALL
SELECT EmplyoeeID, 'Resource' FROM ResourceTable As b
WHERE 
 NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM Master as a
        WHERE a.EmplyoeeID= b.EmplyoeeID
    )
```

Comment: Why are you using SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Show us your existing `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE VIEW` statements.

Comment: If you haven't attempted to write the code yourself, we aren't going to attempt to write your code for you.

Comment: the table were created by Alteryx

Comment: *"I am looking at doing union for the two table although the columns are different name."* The columns, in your example, have the same names, `ID`, `EmployeeID`, and `Name`, though when using a `UNION (ALL)` only the names/aliases of the columns in the *first* `SELECT` matter, as they are used to define the final column aliases. `SELECT 1 AS A UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS B;` would only return a column called `A` with 2 rows with the values `1` and `2`.

Comment: `Select a, b, c, 'master' as source from table1 union all select a1, b1, c2, 'resource' from table2` perhaps

Comment: @siggemannen, Thank you for helping. It's working. However, I got everything. I should only get Master records if it already exists in ResourceTable

Comment: Then you add to the resource part of select a `where not exists` that checks so ID doesn't exist in master table

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it via this code

```
Create VIEW AddEmployee  AS
SELECT EmployeeID, 'Master' as Source FROM MasterTable
UNION ALL
SELECT EmployeeID, 'Resource' FROM ResourceTable As b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MasterTable as a WHERE a.EmployeeID= b.EmployeeID)
```

Comment: Great work. Just a little small nitpick, usually people do SELECT 1 inside the where exists because it doesn't matter what you select as long as it's anything but SELECT * is in general good to avoid

Comment: @siggemannen, Thanks for the suggestion will follow this

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing, because you make the statement:

> I should only get Master records if it already exists in ResourceTable

But your stated expected output includes records from the Master table which don't exist in the Resource table.

I'm assuming that the edited in comment is the correct question and you just forgot to update your expected output.

So, setting up your example data:

```
create table #MasterTable
(
    ID int,
    EmployeeID int,
    [Name] varchar(20)
)

create table #ResourceTable
(
    ID int,
    EmployeeID int,
    [Name] varchar(20)
)

insert into #MasterTable values
(1,123,'John'),
(2,456,'Nico'),
(3,768,'Jam'),
(4,342,'Jom'),
(5,142,'Carlo')

insert into #ResourceTable values
(1,123,'John'),
(2,456,'Nico'),
(3,444,'Don'),
(4,143,'Addie')
```

This query gets the result I believe you're actually asking for (all records which are in the Resource table, therefore excluding any which **only** exist in the Master table):

```
select
    r.ID,
    r.EmployeeID,
    r.[Name],
    case when m.EmployeeID is not null then 'MasterTable' else 'ResourceTable' end as [Source]
from #ResourceTable r
left join #MasterTable m on r.EmployeeID = m.EmployeeID
```

| ID | EmployeeID | Name | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | John | MasterTable |
| 2 | 456 | Nico | MasterTable |
| 3 | 444 | Don | ResourceTable |
| 4 | 143 | Addie | ResourceTable |

If this is not what you wanted, then you need to clarify your question to either update your expected output to agree with the bolded comment you edited in, or vice-versa.